# Calculate transistor collector and base resistors values for driving LED with GPIO

Tags: led, raspberry-pi, gpio

I try to learn how to use a transistor and how to calculate the necessary resistances. Here's what I calculate for the moment. I do not know at all if I left properly and if my equations are good. I think the equation for R2 is not good. How should I go about it? I also learn to read the data sheet of a transistor. Any help is welcome. Thank you

**EDIT: it's WORKING**

*using factor of 10, using β = 100, R1 = 55Ω and R2 = 1325Ω precisely using potentiometers ... The LED does light when I connect a voltage 3.3 V on the base of the transistor, success.*

[image]

Comment: For a start: \$ \frac{5-3.9}{0.02} \neq 250\$

Comment: Thank's for that, I'm confuse

Comment: I think the equation for R2 looks OK. I would do: \$V(R_2)\$ = 3.3 - 0.65 = 2.65V. I **choose** a base current that is 10x smaller than the collector current of 20 mA (to make the transistor operate well into saturation mode) so \$I_B\$ = 20 mA / 10 = 2 mA. Then R2 = 2.65 V / 2 mA = 1325 ohm, same as you get.

Comment: Make sure to use seperate variables: \$ U_S = 5.0\$V in the left upper corner, but  \$ U_S = 3.3\$V in the right lower corner

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thank you very much. It's reassuring for me beginner like me. But I still do not understand why we chose a value 10 times lower, which comes 10, I can not make the relationship for the moment because of my small level. I take my informations on different Internet website and it is not explain.

Comment: And wouldn't \$ \alpha = \frac{\beta}{\beta+1} \neq 0.65 \$?

Comment: @Huisman, thank you very much. Your 'Us' notation recommendations are for better readability of the calculation? or other chosen where I do not think?

Comment: @Huisman, for α I don't know. I also deduced that it was Vbe(sat) on the data sheet but I am in blurring for the moment.

Comment: *But I still do not understand why we chose a value 10 times lower* As explained: I **choose** the factor to be 10. The NPN has a \$\beta\$ = 100, so if I would use that  and make \$I_B\$ smaller (0.2 mA) then the NPN sets the current as it will be close to **active mode** operation. I don't want that! I want **saturation**. So I apply 10x more \$I_B\$ to make sure.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, thant you very much again, I think understand now.

Comment: Regarding \$\alpha\$: \$V_{BE,sat}\ne \alpha\$ \$V_{BE,sat}\$ is simply a value we look up, for 99% of transistors it is 0.6 V to 0.7 V as the BE junction of an NPN is just like a diode. As an exercise do the calculation for R2 again with \$V_{BE,sat}\$=0.6 V and \$V_{BE,sat}\$=0.7 V and see what changes: almost nothing.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, thank you. For my case with β = 100 (I'm not sure because I learn how to read transistor datasheet, for the moment I take 10mA ref. min value where β = 100)  : α=β/β+1 = 100/101 = 0.99 , so α = 0.99 but not VBE,sat value. VBE,sat ≠ α . This is right ?

Comment: You can forget about \$\alpha\$, you don't need it. Also note that although the datasheet says \$\beta\$=100, the actual value can change **a lot**. Like between 50 and 200. It depends on the actual transistor you're using. For properly designed circuits this does not matter, that's why I use a 10x larger \$I_B\$ so that even if \$\beta\$=50, I'm still OK and well in saturation.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, thank you again :). Actually do not ask me why I linked this to Vbe (sat) surely because I tried to find a starting point. But if I forget α, what is the good equation for finding R2 or RB please ?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, Sorry I'm so confused, my Vbe(sat) in my R2 equation is good or not? It is not good to associate Alpha with Vbe (sat) because it is not at all the same thing if I understand correctly but this does not tell me if the equation for R2 is good or not.

Comment: You're **overthinking** this. I wrote: ignore \$\alpha\$ so why are you still asking about it? It was already said that your calculations are correct. Stop overthinking!

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, Sorry I do not really speak English and this associated with my low level in electronics, to assimilate everything is complicated. And on this same post yet, another person gave me equations and the values ​​do not correspond to anything ... R2 = (Vs - Vbe (sat) / (10 * (If / Beta))),  I try to replace the numeric values ​​with the reference values ​​of the data sheet to correctly see the equation-level matches, the base actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I drive from Atmega328P and similar a lot.  Need to limit the current from the uC. These methods work pretty well, and the transistor characteristics do not matter so much. If you have known values (Vbe, Vce, Vf, Rds), plug those in.

For R1, base resistor, assuming Vbe of 0.7V for R1, and current flow of 20mA to push transistor into saturation, then (5V - Vbe)/.02A = resistor.

If a MOSFET, have to deal with gate input capacitance, then its just 5V/.02A for the resistor. That capacitance looks like a short (to Gnd when driving high, and to Vcc if driving it low), so the resistor just limits the initial current rush as the cap charges or discharges.

Select R2 to limit the LED current. Assuming Vce of 0.7V, Vf of LED (you can use a 5V source and 1K resistor and measure it), then R2 = (Vsource - Vf - Vce)/0.02A (20mA) = resistor value. Maybe even solve for 10mA, or 5mA, modern day LEDs can be really bright at 20mA, and it also depends on the lens type, and the color.  Old LEDs had poor brightness, new ones are much brighter.

Comment: Thank you, If I understand correctly: `$Vs = 5.;
$If = 0.02;
$Vbe(sat) = 0.65;
$R1 = (($Vs - $Vbe(sat))/$If) = 217.5 Ohms;

$Vf = 3.9;
$Vce(sat) = 0.2 ;
$R2 = (($Vs - $Vf - $Vce(sat))/$If)= 45 Ohms;`

Comment: For me R2 = RB ... I'm confuse again

Comment: Looks correct. Vf of 3.9V is high, is that a white, or blue, or IR LED? Those typically have high Vf like that.  (5V - 3.9V - 0.2V)/45 ohm = 20mA.  Standard values of 50 ohm would do fine for R1, and 220 for R1.

Comment: Just reverse them then.  R2 = (5V - Vbe)/.02A. R1 = (5V - Vf - Vce)/.02A.  Just a name at this point. Base resistor of 220 ohm, LED current limit resistor of 50 ohm.

Comment: Thank you again, It's a blue led 3.9@20mA. "50 ohm would do fine for R1, and 220 for R1" ? Sorry , Did you mean 220 Ohms for R2 ? knowing that for my case R2 = RB ? (I am not English and I find it difficult to find myself :)

Comment: Yes, there was a typo in my answer. R2 / Rb = 220, R1 / Rled = 50.

Comment: Thank you , but I do not know why I feel that something is wrong with the calculations. If I look on this site [link](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/06/control-led-using-gpio-output-pin/), the value of RB (R2 for me) is really far from the one I find. and my GPIO is 3.3 V.

Comment: Maybe something like this (I take Vce and Vbe SAT on datasheet it is good or not ? `$Vs = 3.3;
$If = 0.02;
$Vbe(sat) = 0.65;
$R2 = ($Vs - $Vbe(sat))/$If = 132.5 Ohms;

$Vs = 5.;
$Vf = 3.9;
$Vce(sat) = 0.2 ;
$R1 = ($Vs - $Vf - $Vce(sat))/$If = 45 Ohms`

Comment: Yes, Rb = (3.3V - 0.65V)/.02A = 132.5 ohm.  Use a 120 ohm, I think that is the next lowest standard value.  3.3V will likely be a little below 3.3V, so 120 would still provide ~ 20mA.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Finally, it does not work, I tried with a factor of 10, using β = 100, R1 = 55 Ω and R2 = 1325 KΩ precisely using potentiometers ... The LED does not light when I connect a voltage 3.3 V on the base of the transistor.

Comment: What happened to the 120 that was discussed?

Comment: I have read @Bimpelrekkie comments and followed, also, his recommendations .

Comment: All tutorials on Internet have , for the raspberry, an Rb value of KΩ ... (27K, 33K, I see) ... I don't understand . [link](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/06/control-led-using-gpio-output-pin/) and [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_nCNXY98qyE)

Comment: It's finally working, I was using a bad transistor, sorry for that.

Comment: What resistor values did you end up with?

Comment: 1325Ω work, 132Ω also work, I think, because transistor is used as switch and not as an amplifier, 20mA of current passes through the LED all the time, same if Ib change... ?